# HTTP or HTTPS (SSL) for Azure blob storage within Microsoft data centres

Tags: azure-blob-storage

Is HTTP or HTTPS (DefaultEndpointsProtocol in the storage connection string) recommended for blob requests within the Azure data centre?  That is, between Azure role instances and blob storage.

I can see that I must use HTTPS for diagnostics (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString; see Incorrect DiagnosticsConnectionString Setting heading [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg465402.aspx)).

I suppose that HTTP will be faster, although I have no measurements to say whether it is material.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no official Microsoft guidance on using HTTP or HTTPS with Azure Storage.

It will be faster to use HTTP as the [HTTPS handshake](http://robertheaton.com/2014/03/27/how-does-https-actually-work/) is not taking place. Security within the data center should not be a concern.

With [HTTP/2 protocol](https://http2.akamai.com/) support on Azure, the performance difference will diminished. The [Azure team is working on it](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/6510044-support-http-2-and-spdy).

On the other hand, HTTPS is secure and secure by default is a good practice.